# Setting up Hibernate+C3P0 in Spring

Tags: spring, hibernate, netbeans, libraries, c3p0

I am using Netbeans as my IDE, currently developing an Web app using:

- Spring 3
- Hibernate 3
- MySQL

I'm relying on netbeans to build the project(in contrast to others using maven). On deployment, the console shows this error:

...noClassDefFoundError: com/mchange/v2/c3p0/DataSources

I've already added the jar file to the Hibernate library.
*(And oh, this is my first time asking here. Needed 10 points to post the screenshot.)*

So I'm confused why would it need THAT class. (whatever that class does.)
Ideas why did this happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've finally manage to solve the problem. The c3p0 distribution has 3 .jar files on the lib directory. I initially added the "c3p0*.jar" only. Which in turn produces the error. 
It needs the OTHER jar file, mchange-commons*.jar in the directory. Hope this helps to others stuck in here.

Answer (score 1):

Download this jar **mchange-commons-java-0.2.3.4.jar**. This helps me to resolve the issue.

Comment: :Thanks for mentioning a clear info over .jar name & its version

Answer (score 0):

C3P0 is used to support connection pooling. See http://www.mchange.com/projects/c3p0/ for further information on C3P0 and https://community.jboss.org/wiki/HowToConfigureTheC3P0ConnectionPool for information on configuring C3P0 with Hibernate.

Comment: I'm aware that it's used for connection pooling. I'm currently configuring it with hibernate.cfg.xml, and as soon as it sees a config using c3p0, it stops - spitting that error.

Comment: The error is because an appropriate c3p0 jar file has not been found on your classpath. You can download c3p0 from http://sourceforge.net/projects/c3p0/ The current jar c3p0-0.9.2.1.jar contains the missing DataSources class file.

Comment: I've solved it already, (I missed the OTHER jar file, mchange-commons*.jar in the directory.) Anyway, the thanks for the response!

Answer (score 0):

1. Add this jar file ["c3p0-0.9.2.1.jar"](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1Oq5Qalsesr9VWh9hKwJpnPW68z4hCAsl) to library
2. If you are still getting the error, you need to remove and add again Hibernate library because this "c3p0-0.9.2.1.jar" is conflict version with c3p0 in Hibernate library